# php Icalendar feed is not valid

Tags: php, icalendar

I have this code that generates an ical feed

```
$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Booking Hosting Calendar//EN
VERSION:2.0";
$ical.=booking_ical_get_booking_dates($post_id);
$ical.="
END:VCALENDAR";

header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=calendar.ics');
print $ical;
exit;
```

When i try to validate the feed(via url) on icalendar.org i get this error message

```
Lines not delimited by CRLF sequence near line # 1
```

If i just copy paste the content of the file in the same generator it will validate.

I assume is the way i'm ending the lines and I've try adding

```
echo "\r\n"
```

after each line or using PHP_EOL but with no luck. Any suggestions ?

Update
Now the code looks like this

```
$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
$ical .="PRODID:-//Booking Hosting Calendar//EN\r\n";
$ical .="VERSION:2.0\r\n";
$ical.=booking_ical_get_booking_dates($post_id);
$ical.="END:VCALENDAR";

header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=calendar.ics');
print $ical;
exit;
```

But i still get the same error.

Comment: Why would you use PHP_EOL? The constant that is specifically meant to result in _different_ “versions” of a line break, depending on the platform the script is running on? If you want \r\n, then _use_ \r\n.

Comment: I edited the question since not everything was visible - i try adding "\r\n" before using PHP_EOL but did not work.

Comment: The line breaks you have inside the values you assign are dependent on how you save the file. I would simply use the following form instead: `$ical = "foo\r\n"; $ical .= "Next line\r\n"; …` - so append one line each, and include the proper line breaks at the end of each. No “implicit” line break by writing a single text literal over multiple lines.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did that (see the update) but the problem is still there.

Comment: Now there seems to be a line break missing between the variable value you insert, and the following line, `END:VCALENDAR`. (And what does `booking_ical_get_booking_dates` return, does that include proper line breaks wherever any might be necessary?)

Comment: The error is at line 1 : Lines not delimited by CRLF sequence near line # 1. I already did the suggested changes.

Comment: Have you opened the file with a text editor, and checked what it contains? (Or preferably a hex editor, so that you can check which line breaks are used as well.)

Comment: With notepad- everything looks normal. If i copy the content and use it on https://icalendar.org/validator it will validate. Here is a link to a empty calendar https://devme.wprentals.org/ical/?ical=bc2c32dca67865358bb8b300b1dd89bf

Comment: That empty calendar does not make the validator complain about line breaks, but only says it is missing any components. So what’s the difference between your “empty” calendar, and a filled one then?

Comment: With data in calendar we get same error on line 1. The link i posted in prev comment has some event data now.

Comment: When I download this and check it in a hex editor, there is only `0A` in the position of the line breaks, whereas it should be `0D 0A`.

Comment: i see 0D 0A:  http://prntscr.com/lkou2m

Comment: Yeah now I do, too - some sort of caching issue maybe?

Comment: Have you checked out the PHP library they are offering over there to read and write iCal files? https://icalendar.org/php-library.html Maybe using that would be less trouble, than trying to figure out what the issue is here?

Comment: Not yet-- but i guess this is the next step. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: In your linked empty calendar above I only see CRLF on first two lines, others only had LF.
I use echo chr(13).chr(10);
actually I use a function to handle each line in case it also needs 'folding' (ie > 75 characters - needs CRLF followed by white space.)

Answer (score 0):

Your booking_ical_get_booking_dates function must be missing the CRLF for each line. First two lines doing ok, rest not.

Also see my comment re folding lines - oftentimes if folks don'thave the CRLF correct, they usually also haven't folded long lines. See https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-1-content-lines.html